# Java mail API smtp-host automatically converting into localhost

Tags: java, proxy, jakarta-mail

I have below API to send smtp email:

```
void sendSMTPMail(File emlFile)throws Exception {
        String host = "smtp.host";
        int port =25;
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        InputStream source = new FileInputStream(emlFile);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session,source);

        Transport.send(message);
    }
```

When Transport.send(message) tries to send email the mentioned host say "smtp.host" (some remote smtp host) automatically converting into localhost, and trying to make smtp connection at localhost, In some system its perfectly connecting with smtp.host but in some system its not. 
error log from system where its not working:

> smtp host: smtp.host(edited), port=25.
>   uri in select proxy: socket://localhost:25, host: localhost
>   Returning previousSelector (DIRECT), host: localhost
>   Unable to send smtp message. MessageID: <86717532.2.1501062622633>
>   MailMonitor$SendMailTask.run():215->MailMonitor$SendMailTask.sendSMTPMail():277>MailMonitor$SendMailTask.sendSMTPMail():277

There is one API which tries to find proxy mapped for this smtp host but that API is receiving localhost as parameter:

```
@Override
public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
    String host = uri!=null?uri.getHost():null;
    Logger.info("uri in select proxy: "+uri+", host: "+host);
    if (urlToProxyMap.containsKey(uri.getHost()))
    {
        final List<Proxy> proxies = urlToProxyMap.get(uri.getHost());
        //proxy = one suitable proxy
        ...
        return proxy;
    }
    else if (defaultProxy != null && uri.getScheme().toLowerCase().startsWith("http")) {
        Logger.info("Returning default proxy: "+defaultProxy+", host:"+host);
        return defaultProxy;
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.info("Returning previousSelector (DIRECT), host: "+host);
        return this.previousSelector.select(uri);
    }
}
```

It could be a weird question but any pointer would be helpful

Comment: From your method _**select(URI uri)**_ which logger messages are logged? Can you post them too?

Comment: Fix the [common mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) and test again.

Comment: @RavinderReddy, log message displayed as:
uri in select proxy: socket://localhost:25, host: localhost

Comment: _**@Santosh**_: It is because of the first statement in your *select* method. `String host = uri!=null?uri.getHost():null;` You must be passing the `URI` as `localhost` and the same is passed as `smtp.host`. Instead, you should read smtp host from your predefined `properties` object when sending a message. That would resolve the issue.

Comment: @RavinderReddy actually API select(URI uri) itself receiving localhost instead of smtp.host, somewhere before calling this API smtp.host:25 is getting converted into localhost:25.

Comment: @jmehrens I saw the common-mistakes will try and see if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was that I was using Use of getDefaultInstance instead of getInstance, after I changed that line it stopped overwriting the value of mail.smtp.host for localhost